# react testing librarie mock useSelector redux error

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, redux, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have a test where I need mock the useSelector from react redux, now when I do these work I have a problem render always return a undefined, these happend after create el mock of redux -> useSelector:

```
jest.mock('react-redux', () => ({
  useSelector: jest.fn(fn => fn()),
  useDispatch: () => jest.fn(),
}));
```

when I implement these have a error:

> const wrapper = render
>
> render -> is undefined
>
> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)
>   or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You
>   likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in,
>   or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

I get this error in this line:

```
  const wrapper = render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <EventsList></EventsList>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
  );
```

when I debug these without the line of jest `jest.mock('react-redux', ...` work fine.

but have another error:

> An error occurred while selecting the store state: Cannot read
>   property 'data' of undefined.

In my component that I'm testing I create a list and get this list of store of redux with useSelector and useDispatch. these is my test completed.

```
jest.mock('react-redux', () => ({
  useSelector: jest.fn(fn => fn()),
  useDispatch: () => jest.fn(),
}));

afterEach(cleanup);

describe('<EventList />', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });

  afterAll(() => {
    jest.restoreAllMocks();
  });

  const mockStore = configureStore([]);
  const events: Array<IEvent> = [
    {
      title: 'Evento de prueba 1',
      description: '<p>Evento de prueba 1</p>',
      venue: 'Lab 2 Jalasoft La paz',
      date: new Date(),
      booking: false,
      typeEvent: eventType.online,
      state: 'PUBLISHED',
      url: '',
      ownerId: '5e4d74a2a258adb30001962f80',
      id: '5e4e91a3c3145e0ds0016100e6',
    },
    {
      title: 'Evento de prueba 2',
      description: '<p>Evento de prueba 2</p>',
      venue: 'Lab 2 Jalasoft La paz',
      date: new Date(),
      booking: false,
      typeEvent: eventType.online,
      state: 'PUBLISHED',
      url: '',
      ownerId: '5e4d74a2a258b30001962f80',
      id: '5e4e91a3c3145e00016100e6',
    },
  ];

  const store = mockStore((state: any) => {
    return {
      data: events,
      loading: false,
      error: false,
    };
  });

  const wrapper = render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <EventsList></EventsList>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
  );

  test('descripv', () => {
    expect(wrapper.getByRole(/form/i)).toBeInTheDocument;
  });
});
```